# Why is JavaScript giving me random numbers for simple arithmetic operations?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
    var negativeOdds = document.getElementById("negative").value;
    var positiveOdds = document.getElementById("positive").value;

    console.log(positiveOdds);

    var positiveImplied = 100 / (positiveOdds + 100);
```

The result for var = positiveImplied is always something like 0.000843 when it's supposed to be around 0.454. I've tried countless of combinations with the parenthesis and it still gives me the same random answers. I console logged the positiveOdds variable to make sure it's getting the right info and it clearly is.

Anyone know what's up?

What I forgot to add is that it works perfectly fine in the other scenario:

```
var negativeOdds = document.getElementById("negative").value;
    var positiveOdds = document.getElementById("positive").value;

    console.log(positiveOdds);

    var positiveImplied = (100) / (positiveOdds + 100);
    var negativeImplied = (-(negativeOdds))/((-(negativeOdds)) + 100);
```

Works fine for negativeImplied, doesn't work at all for positive.

Edit: Works fine with parseInt. But still I don't understand how I don't have to use parseInt for negativeImplied, but have to for positiveImplied.

Comment: Just add `+` in front of `document.get.....value;`

Comment: Try using `parseInt()` on the `positiveOdds` var

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: As mentioned by others... you need to explicitly convert those values to numeric types.  You are likely doing math on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```
var negativeOdds = Number(document.getElementById("negative").value);
var positiveOdds = Number(document.getElementById("positive").value);
var positiveImplied = 100 / (positiveOdds + 100);
```